Should we lock all of the retail brokerage questions?
There are a number of older questions about retail brokerages. Here are a few:

Option trading API other than Interactive Brokers
Which brokers offer a .NET stock trading API?
Which brokers offer a Python stock trading API?

These questions merely invite non-quants to post. I propose to lock (not close or delete) these questions to prevent future "answers".

I've locked these questions and deleted some of the worst answers on them. If anyone is curious why I don't want retail questions on a site for professional quants, look no further than this question; all four posts (question, comment, answers) come from users who have 1 rep.
